# Conditionally add values to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is my code where the dictionary is created:

```
for table in get_json():
    updated_user_dict = {
        "email": table['email'],
        "company": table['company'],
        "userinfo": if args.u: 
            [update_user(dic, ssh_session)
            for dic in table['userinfo']]
    }
```

I only want to add:

```
[update_user(dic, ssh_session)
            for dic in table['userinfo']]
```

if `args.u` is `True`. If I have, for example, `args.c`, I want to add something else to `userinfo`.

Is something like this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The keys and values in a dictionary literal can be any expression, as such a conditional expression can easily be used.

You just need to be careful how you type it, values go first and tuples in comprehensions should always have parentheses.

A sample example of a conditional for the value of the dictionary:

```
condition = False    
d = {1: [('a', 'a') for _ in range(2)] if condition else [('b','b') for _ in range(2)]}
```

`condition` is `False` therefore, `d` is initialized with `[('b','b') for _ in range(2)]`:

```
{1: [('b', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]}
```

With two `if` conditions:

```
d = {1: [('a', 'a') for _ in range(2)] if condition else [('b','b') for _ in range(2)] if condition else ('c', 'c')}
```

`condition` is again `False` therefore `('c', 'c')` is used and `d` is now: `{1: ('c', 'c')}`.

Substitute with `arg.u` and `arg.c` and the values you need in a similar fashion.

If the number of conditions you need to examine isn't too large, initialize in the dictionary literal with a conditional expression. If not, it would be more readable to use seperate `if-elif-else` statements.